# How to get a div filled with text from a select box?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have 3 select boxes for day, month and year, see example http://jsfiddle.net/arieanneke/sf73o0w5/

```
var birthday = "";
$('#birthday').change(function () {
var selectedDay = $(this).find(":selected").text();
alert(selectedDay);
birthday = selectedDay + "-";
$("#birthdaytext" ).text(birthday);
})
```

I want to have a div with the selected date in this div, eg 03-02-1970.

How can I make this jquery that the text date is only visible after all of the 3 select boxes are not on there default value day, month and year and that the 3 texts from the select boxes are set to one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below code and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/sf73o0w5/8/) .using below code text append to dive only when all three select box is selected using single change event

HTML

```
  <select name="birthday" id="birthday" class="bday">
   <option value="" selected="selected">DAY</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
  </select> 
 <select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth" class="bday">
   <option value="" selected="selected">MONTH</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
 </select> 
 <select name="birthyear" id="birthyear" class="bday">
  <option value="" selected="selected">YEAR</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1972">1972</option>
 </select> 
  <br /><br />
  <span id="birthdaytext"></span>
```

JQUERY

```
   var birthday = birthmonth = birthyear = "";
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.bday').change(function () {

       if($(this).attr('id') == 'birthday'){
         birthday = $(this).val();
       }

       if($(this).attr('id') == 'birthmonth'){
         birthmonth = $(this).val();
       }

       if($(this).attr('id') == 'birthyear'){
         birthyear = $(this).val();
       }

       if(birthday!= "" && birthmonth!= '' && birthyear !== '' ){
        $('#birthdaytext').text(birthday+"-"+birthmonth+"-"+birthyear);
       }
    });
 })
```

Comment: Tnx, this was did exactly what it must do!

Answer (score 1):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="birthdaytext" style="display: none;">
    <span></span>-
    <span></span>-
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Use the following `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    window.select = {}; // use global variable
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).on('change', function() {
            var $div = $('#birthdaytext')
            ,   name = $(this).attr('name')
            ,   value = $(this).val()
            ,   i = 0;

            if(name == 'birthday') {
                window.select[name] = value ? true : false;
                $div.find('span:eq(0)').text(value);
            } else if(name == 'birthmonth') {
                window.select[name] = value ? true : false;
                $div.find('span:eq(1)').text(value);
            } else if(name == 'birthyear') {
                window.select[name] = value ? true : false;
                $div.find('span:eq(2)').text(value);
            }

            for(name in window.select) // check if global variable is all true
                if(window.select[name] == true) ++i;

            if(i == 3) // if it is
                $div.show();
            else
                $div.hide();
        });
    });

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1o7dzgc/2/)

Comment: Tnx, but this one give after each change in the selectbox, directly the day, month or year. I want to have this date after all 3 selectboxes are filled in.

Comment: I have edited my answer. As such, the `<div>` will be displayed if, and only if, the three values have been filled. Extra feature: it will be hidden back if 1+ of the 3 goes back to default.

Comment: Tnx alot! The extra feature is simple but great!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote this answer and also accept it if it suited your requirements better and you ended up using it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you looking for this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sf73o0w5/7/)

```
var birthday = "";
$('#birthday,#birthmonth,#birthyear').change(function () {
var selectedDay = $(this).find(":selected").text();
console.log(selectedDay);
if(this.id!="birthyear")
    birthday = selectedDay + "-";
else {
    birthday = selectedDay;
     $("#birthdaytext" ).show();
}
$("#birthdaytext" ).text($("#birthdaytext" ).text()+birthday);
});
```

Comment: Tnx, but this one give me also after each update of the selectbox, a part of the date. I want to get the date completely after all 3 selectboxes are set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)** and `.join()` to get values from multiple `<select>`

```js
var birthday;
var select = $('select');
select.change(function() {
  var count = 0;
  birthday = select.map(function() {
    $(':selected', this).val().length ? count++ : false;
    return $(':selected', this).val();
  }).get().join('-');
  if (count == 3) {
    $("#birthdaytext").text(birthday);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="birthday" id="birthday">
  <option value="" selected="selected">DAY</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
</select>
<select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth">
  <option value="" selected="selected">MONTH</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
</select>
<select name="birthyear" id="birthyear">
  <option value="" selected="selected">YEAR</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1972">1972</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<span id="birthdaytext"></span>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf73o0w5/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML

```
<select name="birthday" id="birthday">
    <option value="" selected="selected">DAY</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
</select> 
<select name="birthmonth" id="birthmonth">
    <option value="" selected="selected">MONTH</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
</select> 
<select name="birthyear" id="birthyear">
    <option value="" selected="selected">YEAR</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
</select> 
<br /><br />
<span id="birthdaytext" style="display:none;"></span>
```

and this is JS:

```
var birthday = "";
$('#birthday,#birthmonth,#birthyear').change(function () {
    var selectedDay = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    alert(selectedDay);
    if(this.id!="birthyear")
        birthday = selectedDay + "-";
    else {
        birthday = selectedDay;
         $("#birthdaytext" ).show();
    }
    $("#birthdaytext" ).text($("#birthdaytext" ).text()+birthday);
})
```

I think it will help..

Comment: Tnx, close but not close enough .... ;-). It works great when I do the normal thing, fill in in the right order day, month and year. But when I begin with year, I get a wrong date (beginning with year)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var birthday = "";
var selectedDay = "";
var selectedMonth = "";
var selectedYear = "";
var complete=false;

$('#birthday').change(function () {
    selectedDay = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    if(complete==true) {
         birthday = selectedDay + "-" + selectedMonth + "-" + selectedYear;
         $("#birthdaytext").html(birthday);

     }


});

$('#birthmonth').change(function () {
    selectedMonth = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    if(complete==true) {
         birthday = selectedDay + "-" + selectedMonth + "-" + selectedYear;
         $("#birthdaytext").html(birthday);

     }
});

$('#birthyear').change(function () {
    var selectedYear = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    birthday = selectedDay + "-" + selectedMonth + "-" + selectedYear;
    $("#birthdaytext").html(birthday);
    complete=true;

});
```

Comment: Tnx, but this one will also fill in the date after the year selectbox is changed so when somebody start with changing the year, there will be an incorrect date.

Comment: I have changed, does this fits for you?